# Can a mu-metal enclosed compass measure the earth's field?

Tags: magnetometer

I am thinking about using a combination of mu-metal, a faraday cage, and spacial separation to reduce magnetic interference from a brushless motor on a compass sensor.

The compass will be used to calculate heading.   If the vehicle that it is attached to is standing still or slowly rotating, however, will earth's magnetic field be shielded by the mu-metal?   The following is a quote from Wikipedia:

> The high permeability of mu-metal provides a low reluctance path for
>   magnetic flux, leading to its use in magnetic shields against static
>   or slowly varying magnetic fields

[image]

A slowly rotating or fixed compass would experience a static or slowly varying magnetic field from the earth, no?   So would the mu-metal interfere with the compass's readings?

I could always just eliminate the mu-metal and use only a faraday shield, which I know don't affect static or slowly changing magnetic fields.

EDIT: someone please let me know if there is a more appropriate SE site on which to ask this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use mumetal to shield the magnetic field of the motor from affecting the magnetometer. The magnetometer should not be shielded though, because any shielding will prevent the earths magnetic field from reaching the magnetometer.